# How can I update and then restore?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, restore

I've just been sent a replacement iPhone. I don't have a computer at the moment so I've gone to restore it during the set up. It shows the latest iPhone backup as 08:42 which is the one that I want to restore to but it won't allow me to restore to it as it says iOS 8.3 Required.

How can I update it so that I can restore it? I could set it up as a new iPhone and then update it, but when I wipe it to get back to the restore screen I'll be in the same situation surely.

Comment: Borrow a friends computer or to go to your nearest Apple Store would be your best options.

Answer (score 1):

I have realised that wiping the iPhone does not downgrade it, so it was as simple as setting it up as a new iPhone, updating it, wiping it, and then restoring.

This can all be done without a computer (as per my question), unlike the other answers.

Comment: That's correct. iOS do no longer require you to plug your device into a computer and iTunes for most tasks. The only time you need to plug it into a computer is to do some low-level restoring (DFU).

Comment: You can (and should!) accept your own answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just update on the iPhone.
Then when you want to restore, connect to iTunes and "restore from backup" (your old phone), this brings back the latest backup data (w/o iOS) from your old phone.

Comment: I don't have a computer.